# How to delete a file with given inode number from unmountable drive

Tags: boot, mount, hard-drive, recovery-mode

This is fourth time in 2 years, my machine has refused to boot. Everytime different error. Last 3 times, I have sacrified the data and installed a fresh ubuntu. But this time I have large risk. I am trying to get back my system. Here are the details of failure...

1. Machine failed to boot, as it couldn't mount some hard disk. Gave a message saying try to 'systemclt default' i.e. boot in default mode, but didn't work. I was dropped to same prompt with same message.
2. In recovery mode, i dropped to root, and tried to mount home drive /dev/sda3, which failed with a message saying check dmesg|tail . Output of which said about a corrupt offset.
3. Checking other answers here, I mounted the drive on a local folder using 'noload' option that skips journal checking.
4. I am able to see all my home folder data, along with a wierd file. I believe this i the cause of the issue. I have got the inode number of it. It's a 0 byte file.

Now, I think if I somehow delete this file, I should be able to mount it in write mode and also be able to boot normally. This is the step I am stuck at.

Any way to delete this file? It's currently mounted in readonly mode. But we know the drive number and inode number.

Any help please.

Using ubuntu 15.10

The error
[image]

The 3rd file from bottom looks the culprit
[image]

Comment: Adding images of errors in 5 mins

Comment: Please don't close the question. What is wrong with my question, please comment and i'll try to improve. As per me this is a valid question.

Comment: I don't think the weird file is the cause. Also, what you see in image is not inode number, it's just it's size

Comment: yes, i know, it's not in the pic, but i see the inode number by `ls -i`

Comment: @Serg Any way to recover?

Comment: There's something you can try, but I can't exactly post a proper answer right now, since I'm using cellphone. I'll get back to you later.